# Visual studio program too add resistors in series from input. C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2019, desktop-application

[image]

```
private void seriesres_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i=0;
        double finalanswer=0;

        string phrase = Conversion_Value.Text;  // input to string
        double[] doubles = phrase.Split(',').Select(Double.Parse).ToArray();
        double numresistors = double.Parse(num_resistors.Text); // number of resistors
        for (i = 0; i >= numresistors; i++)
        {
            finalanswer = finalanswer + doubles[i];
        }
        Answer.Text = finalanswer.ToString("F6"); // STRING TO DOUBLE WITH 6 DECIMAL PLACES

    }
```

This is my code in visual studio 19 for windows forms c#.  I am attempting to take the text box input separated by "," and turn that into a doubles array, and use a for loop to add them all together for resistors in series. the image shows the program and what the output is when the information in the boxes is entered and series is clicked.

Comment: hey, may i ask what your question is. i assume you want to generate textboxes with those values, which then get the values as text.
And then add them to the forms application, to visualize the resistor network

Comment: I updated the post to include the picture,  my goal is to have the double finalanswer = 6 in the picture, right now the program only runs when I initialize the variable final answer and it won't change from the initial value.

Comment: Your problem is the `>=` in your `for` loop, it should be `<`. You don't even need the `numresistors` variable or textbox, you can just use `doubles.Length`.

Comment: @Big72Red ahh ok, take a look an Ian`s comment, this should solve your issue ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is incorrect.

Try this

```
       var values = Conversion_Value.Text.Split(',').Select(Double.Parse).ToArray();

        double finalanswer =0;
        foreach (var v in values)
        {
            finalanswer +=v;
        }

        Answer.Text = finalanswer.ToString("F6");
```